# Como faço para gerar um IP automático(DHCP) em VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ip

Boa tarde, gostaria de saber como posso estar gerando um IP automático(DHCP) em VB.NET e se tem necessidade de gerar as Mascara, Gateway e DNS automático também? 
Ou nesse caso de usar o IP Automático, eu teria que usar um padrão de de Mascara, Gateway e DNS?

Comment: Explique o que é gerar um IP automático. Para que precisa disto?

Comment: Eu imagino que o OP esteja se referindo a DHCP.

Comment: Estou configurando um modulo e em um exemplo distribuído pelo fabricante, ele me da 2 opções, 1 que seria um IP Fixo e 2  um IP que o sistema deles gera, mas eu estou usando esses exemplos para gerar o meu projeto, porém na hora de gerar o IP automático eu soube fazer.

Comment: Ver se isso te ajuda: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/220874

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUZohsAxPxQ

Comment: Isso mesmo, DHCP

Comment: Neste case você precisa de um serviço DHCP habilitado para o seu segmento de rede, @FelipeWalleg. Routers domésticos geralmente oferecem o serviço. Empresas podem ter servidores dedicados. Em uma janela de comando, digite `ipconfig /all` - o servidor DHCP estará listado como *DHCP Server*.

Comment: Certo, achei isso aqui.
Então tenho que usar esse IP?
E a Mascara, Gateway? Uso as que apareceram ?

Comment: Se o módulo está configurado para usar um IP automático, você não precisa implementar nada no lado VB.NET; o ambiente operacional se encarregará de obter um IP. informações como máscara e gateway são necessários apenas para IPs estáticos.

Comment: Foi o que eu imaginei, não é um problema de programação.

Comment: Exato, @bigown.

Comment: Entendi.
no caso eu forneço por forma de uma função um XML para configura-lo, acredito que eu deixe essa parte de IP em vazio quando for DHCP 
'<tipoLan>DHCP</tipoLan>'
'<lanIP></lanIP>'
'<lanMask></lanMask>'
'<lanGW></lanGW>'
 Assim?

Comment: @FelipeWalleg Dependerá da implementação, mas eu diria que sim. Bons testes!

Answer (score 1):

**Um computador com base no Windows configurado para usar DHCP pode atribuir-se automaticamente um endereço IP se um servidor DHCP não estiver disponível.** Por exemplo, isso pode ocorrer em uma rede sem um servidor DHCP ou em uma rede na qual um servidor DHCP esteja temporariamente desativado para manutenção.

A INAN (autoridade de números atribuídos da Internet) reservou o número 169.254.0.0-169.254.255.255 para o endereçamento APIPA. Como resultado, a APIPA fornece um endereço garantido contra conflitos com endereços que podem ser roteados.

Após atribuir um endereço IP ao adaptador de rede, o computador pode usar TCP/IP para se comunicar com outro computador conectado à mesma rede local e também configurado para APIPA ou que tenha o endereço IP definido manualmente para o intervalo de endereços 169.254.x.y (no qual x.y representa a identificação exclusiva do cliente) com uma máscara de sub-rede de 255.255.0.0. Observe que o computador não consegue comunicar-se com computadores em outras sub-redes ou com computadores que não usam endereçamento IP privado automático. Por padrão, o endereçamento de IP privado automático está habilitado.

Talvez você deseje desabilitá-lo em um dos seguintes casos:

- A rede usa roteadores.
- A rede está conectada à Internet sem um servidor NAT ou proxy.

Exceto se as mensagens relacionadas a DHCP estiverem desabilitadas, as mensagens DHCP notificarão ao alternar entre o endereçamento DHCP e o endereçamento de IP privado automático. Se as mensagens DHCP forem desabilitadas por acidente, é possível ativá-las novamente alterando o valor PopupFlag, na seguinte chave do Registro, de 00 para 01:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\VxD\DHCP

Observe que é necessário reiniciar o computador para que a alteração tenha efeito. Também é possível determinar se o computador está usando APIPA por meio da ferramenta Winipcfg no Windows Millennium Edition (Me), Windows 98 ou Windows 98 Segunda Edição (SE):
Clique em Iniciar, em Executar, digite "winipcfg" (sem aspas) e clique em OK. Clique em Mais informações. Se a caixa Endereço IP de configuração automática contiver um endereço IP dentro do intervalo 169.254.x.x, o endereçamento APIPA estará habilitado. Se houver uma caixa Endereço IP, o endereçamento APIPA não estará habilitado no momento.
No Windows 2000, Windows XP ou Windows Server 2003, é possível determinar se o computador está usando APIPA por meio do comando IPconfig no prompt de comando:

Clique em Iniciar, em Executar, digite "cmd" (sem aspas) e clique em OK para abrir uma janela de linha de comando do MS-DOS. Digite "ipconfig /all" (sem aspas) e pressione a tecla ENTER. Se a linha 'Autoconfiguration Enabled' for "Yes" e 'Autoconfiguration IP Address' for 169.254.x.y (no qual x.y representa a identificação exclusiva do cliente), o computador estará usando APIPA. Se a linha 'Autoconfiguration Enabled' for "No", o computador não estará usando APIPA.
É possível desabilitar o endereçamento APIPA usando qualquer um dos seguintes métodos.

É possível configurar as informações SOBRE TCP/IP manualmente, o que também desabilita o DHCP. É possível desabilitar o endereçamento APIPA (não DHCP) editando o Registro. Você pode fazer isso adicionando a entrada do Registro DWORD "IPAutoconfigurationEnabled" com um valor de 0x0 à seguinte chave do Registro para o Windows Millennium Edition, o Windows98 ou o Windows 98 Second Edition:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\VxD\DHCP
Para o Windows 2000, o Windows XP e o Windows Server 2003, o APIPA pode ser desabilitado adicionando a entrada do Registro DWORD "IPAutoconfigurationEnabled" com um valor de 0x0 à seguinte chave do Registro:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\
Observação A subchave Adapter GUID é um GUID (Identificador Global Exclusivo) para o adaptador de LAN do computador.

Ao especificar um valor de 1 para a entrada IPAutoconfigurationEnabled DWORD habilitará o APIPA, que é o estado padrão quando esse valor é omitido do Registro.
Exemplos nos quais APIPA pode ser útil

**Exemplo 1: sem endereço IP anterior e sem servidor DHCP**

Ao inicializar o computador com base no Windows (configurado para DHCP), serão difundidas três ou mais mensagens "discover". Se um servidor DHCP não responder após a exibição de diversas mensagem discover, o computador com base no Windows atribuirá um endereço de Classe B (APIPA) a si mesmo. Depois, o computador com base no Windows exibirá uma mensagem de erro para o usuário do computador (considerando que nunca atribuiu um endereço IP por um servidor DHCP anteriormente). O computador com com o Windows enviará uma mensagem Discover a cada três minutos na tentativa de estabelecer uma comunicação com um servidor DHCP.

**Exemplo 2: endereço IP anterior e sem servidor DHCP**

O computador verifica um servidor DHCP e se não encontrar nenhum, tenta contatar o gateway padrão. Se o gateway padrão responder, o computador com base no Windows reterá o endereço IP concedido anteriormente. Entretanto, se o computador não receber uma resposta do gateway padrão ou se nenhum for atribuído, o endereçamento APIPA será usado para atribuir a si mesmo um endereço IP. Uma mensagem de erro é exibida para o usuário e as mensagens discover são transmitidas a cada três minutos. Quando um servidor DHCP se fica online, uma mensagem declarando que a comunicação foi restabelecida com o servidor DHCP é gerada.

**Exemplo 3: concessão expira e sem servidor DHCP**

O computador com base no Windows tenta restabelecer a concessão de endereço IP. Se o computador com base no Windows não encontrar um servidor DCHP, atribuirá um endereço IP a si mesmo após gerar uma mensagem de erro. Depois, o computador difundirá quatro mensagens discover e a cada cinco minutos repetirá todo o procedimento até que um servidor DHCP fique online. Assim, é gerada uma mensagem declarando que a comunicação foi restabelecida com o servidor DHCP.